# Calling parent method from a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

(This should be simple. But it has been driving me nuts for many hours.)
I am simply trying to call a ViewController method, from inside its UIView.

myViewController declares and creates a UIView:

```
myUIView = [[viewCreator alloc] init…];
```

and my myViewController also has a method:

```
-(void)inABottle{
    NSLog(@"Hello.");
}
```

Inside the UIView, a UIButton is created. This button has a 'selector' to a method - in the UIView - which then tries to call the 'inABottle' method in the ViewController. Inside the UIView:

```
...
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(isPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)isPressed{
    [myViewController inABottle];// <<< This is where I have spent my day.
}
```

(The ViewController header file is #import ed in the UIView.)

Would really appreciate some help. Surely this should be simples!

Comment: Where are you setting myViewController in your UIView?

Comment: Just in the UIView header:  #import "myViewController.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a property in your view and set it to the current view controller when you create it:

viewcontroller.m:

```
myUIView = [[viewCreator alloc] init...];
myUIView.myViewController = self;
```

view.h:

```
@property (weak) ViewController *myViewController;//weak or assign depending if you are using ARC or not, and ViewController should be the class of your view controller
```

view.m:

```
@synthesize myViewController;
```

Then just call the method like you are in your code in the question.

You should also look into how to use delegates, this is a perfect example of when you should use one.

Comment: Thanks Dan F, I think that will work. But you are right, I will take a closer look at using delegates.

Comment: The property here must be `weak`. Otherwise you create a retain loop and will leak the view and view controller.

Comment: @RobNapier very good point, just force of habit to type it that way

Answer (score 3):

This is what protocols and delegation are for. Think about how `UITableView` handles this problem.

```
@class MyView;
@protocol MyViewDelegate
- (void)myViewIsInABottle:(MyView *)view;
@end

@interface MyView : UIView
@property (weak) id<MyViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation MyView
-(void)isPressed{
  [self.delegate myViewIsInABottle:self];
}
...
@end
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes I will take a closer look at this approach. (It really shouldn't be this difficult though!)

Comment: This kind of decoupling is the heart of MVC. If you want, you can hand a view a direct pointer to its view controller as @DanF notes (though you need to make it weak, not strong), but then you create a hard coupling that makes the code difficult to reuse.

Comment: Update: Learning how to use a delegate / protocol, has been a real challenge, there are so few good, complete examples out there. But I found this one, which has helped enormously: http://timneill.net/2010/11/modal-view-controller-example-part-2/